# Correct path for images in javascript using Cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I am new in cakephp, and I have a script, which I converted to cakephp.
I have there a rotate background that use 4 images like this:

```
$.backstretch([
    "img/bg/1.jpg",
    "img/bg/2.jpg",
    "img/bg/3.jpg",
    "img/bg/4.jpg"
], {
     fade: 1000,
     duration: 8000
});
```

When I open script like name_domain.com with use controller users and action login, it see all that images and all work perfect, but when I try to use `register (controller=>users, action=>signup)` the images are not load. 
But I put `../img....` then is working here and not in index.

How can I link correctly those images. I also try with "/img" but not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a javascript variable in default.ctp

```
var IMAGE_HOST = "<?php echo $this->webroot.'/img/'; ?>";
```

and now you can use it in javascript file too

```
<script>
$.backstretch([
    IMAGE_HOST + "bg/1.jpg",
    IMAGE_HOST + "bg/2.jpg",
    IMAGE_HOST + "bg/3.jpg",
    IMAGE_HOST + "bg/4.jpg"
], {
     fade: 1000,
     duration: 8000
});
```

hope it helps..!!

Comment: That is what i this to solve the problem, thank you for your reply:)

Comment: Great.. Kindly don't forget to accept post as answer.. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

try to use full path something like this.

```
$this->webroot.'img/myimage.jpg'
```

OR

```
$this->Html->url('/img/myimage.jpg')
```

OR

```
<?php Router::url('/img/myimage.jpg')?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but this will not work in javascript file. I need something like that, only that i have to include in a javascript file.

Comment: you may need to copy js part in .ctp file to make it workable

Comment: @Essteffan, I have updated my answer you can also try 3rd option as per the above answer. I feel it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you Ram, i've combine your answoe and Martin's answer and it's working. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

One method is to set a JavaScript variable, and then use that in your subsequent scripts. For example, in your **app/Layouts/default.ctp** file, you could have:

```
<script>
    var img_path = "<?php echo Configure::read('App.imageBaseUrl'); ?>";
</script>
```

And then use it in your scripts like this:

```
<script>
    $.backstretch([
        img_path + "/bg/1.jpg",
        img_path + "/bg/2.jpg",
        img_path + "/bg/3.jpg",
        img_path + "/bg/4.jpg"
    ], {
         fade: 1000,
         duration: 8000
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's a great solution, but i have a small problem. When i am on root (index) is working, but when i'm on /users/signup is add users in link like so: name_domain/users/img/bg/... It's working with Ram solution, like so      var img_path = "<?php  echo $this->webroot ?>";

Comment: I missed that `App.imageBaseUrl` only returns a relative URL. You’ll need to combine it with a reference to your site’s base URL. Something like `$this->webroot . Configure::read('App.imageBaseUrl')`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to save webroot path in your layout so that its scope remain global

```
<div id="webroot" class="hide" data-url="<?php echo $this->webroot;?>"></div>
```

Then use it backstretch js as

```
 var webroot = $('#webroot').attr('data-url');
    $.backstretch([
        webroot+ "img/bg/1.jpg",
        webroot+ "img/bg/2.jpg",
        webroot+ "img/bg/3.jpg",
        webroot+ img/bg/4.jpg"
        ], {
          fade: 1000,
          duration: 8000
});
```

When you use different action having same layout with webroot element, it will keep the correct image path.

Comment: I already did it, but that's another approach, if anyone have the same problem. Thanks you

Comment: I was suggesting this because this is more generic approach